# How to check if shopping cart price rule applied to quote

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules, coupon-codes

I have a shopping cart rule setup which applies a discount if the product has a specific attribute - there's no coupon code involved.

Throughout the site I just need to check whether or not that shopping cart rule has been applied to the quote.

I've tried this:

```
$coupon_code = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
```

But that doesn't work; it only works with coupon codes input by the user.

How would I check if such a shopping cart rule has been applied?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$appliedRuleIds = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAppliedRuleIds();
```

This will give you the ids of the rules applied to the quote separated by comma.
you can turn them into an array like this:

```
$appliedRuleIds = explode(',', $appliedRuleIds);
```

if you want to get the rules applied as objects you can do this:

```
//$rules = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('rule_id' => array('in' => $appliedRuleIds));
$rules =  Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('rule_id' , array('in' => $appliedRuleIds));

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    //do something with $rule
}
```

Comment: hi marius, i have to apply similar solution. but getAppliedRuleIds stores both catalog price rule and shopping cart price rule. Now if the field value is only 6 (which is catalog price rule) and a shopping cart price rule too exists in store with id 6. in this case, with your solution, how can we define which one was applied ? shopping cart price rule or catalog price rule ? any help is appreciated.

Comment: @ReenaParekh. I'm almost certain the `getAppliedRuleIds` does not return the catalog price rules applied to the quote/order. Only shopping cart price rules that are applied.

Comment: Hi @Marius , I too need to get the same thing what you have mentioned in above code in magento2.2.2. So Please tell me how do I solve the same issue in magento 2

Comment: Hi @Marius How can we get discount amount from quote based on rule id?

Answer (score 0):

**For Magento 2**

> **Try This Code**

```
protected $quoteRepository;
protected $ruleData;

public function __construct(
    ...................................................................
    \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomRuleDataFactory $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $ruleData,
    ...................................................................
) {
    ...................................................................
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->ruleData = $ruleData;
    ...................................................................
}

public function execute()
{
    $address = 0;
    $quotesVal = 15
    $quotesData = $this->quoteRepository->get($quotesVal);
    $customerId = (int) $quotesData->getCustomerId();
    $productCount = 0;
    foreach ($quotesData->getAllItems() as $quotesDataKey => $quotesDataVal) {
        $address = $quotesDataVal->getAddress();
        $productCount++;
        break;
    }
    if ($productCount) {
        $address->setCachedItemsAll($quotesData->getAllItems());
        $cartRuleData = $this->ruleData->create()->getCollection();
        foreach ($cartRuleData as $ruleKey => $ruleVal) {
            if ($ruleVal->getConditions()->validate($address)){ // if ($ruleVal->getActions()->validate($address))
                echo "Rule Applied";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***